# How to add products from one category to another category page, without really adding them to that category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I know it is a strange question, but I have hopes that it is possible to do so...

**The problem:**
Is it possible to add products from one category to another category page, if that category has no products?For this example I will use Trampolines as a product.

We have a **MAIN category tree:** sport,leisure>leisure>**trampolines**.

Also, we have **2 more category trees:** 1.) Garden products>**trampolines**.
2.) Children's products>**trampolines**

Is it possible to show products from Main category tree child (trampolines), to another 2 category trees child (trampolines), if those 2 categories don't have any products in them?

I know that I can just put products from MAIN category to another 2 categories, but the problem is in XML file. Other marketplaces get information from our website XML file and they accept just one category, **if XML shows more than one categories, the product is no longer working.**

Thankful for any tips!

Comment: If you ask can u add products from one category to another programmatically yes you can. Its abit confusing what u mean by if there is no products in second tree categories. After you add one product in there your rule is no longer valid ?!? There are some examples here how to assign post to different categories.

Comment: _"but the problem is in XML file"_ - what XML file? Maybe you could modify the (dynamic?) creation of that, to only include one of the categories, if the product belongs to multiple ones?

Comment: @MartinMirchev **Its abit confusing what u mean by if there is no products in second tree categories.**
By saying that, I mean that the products should be displayed from category1 page to category2 and category3 pages, BUT products should not be in category2 and 3. For example category1 page link is bonideco.com/category1, category 2 and 3 links are bonideco.com/category2, bonideco.com/category3. in category2and3 pages should be displayed products from category1. But products should have those categories (2and3) on them.

Comment: @MartinMirchev All this has to be done so that the XML file which exports our products to other marketplaces does not see other categories, but only one (category1). In short, products should be displayed but the products shouldn't be in those categories. Have I now made it clearer what I want to achieve? If not, please ask me and I will try to explain it differently. Thanks!

Comment: If modifying that XML creation is not an option, then you could modify the WC product selection query via a hook (you'd have to check/research which one is appropriate) - so that when you are "on" those category 2 / 3 pages, the query gets modified to include products from category 1 instead.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, this is also an option, but when I'm not a programmer I need PHP help anyway...

Comment: "All this has to be done so that the XML file which exports our products to other marketplaces does not see other categories," . You want to export products FROM this website in xml or import from xml TO this website ? If you import from some xml with create_post hook you can modify how its going to be imported and assign the product to other categories. If you dont have skills in php i would recommend hire someone.

Comment: I want to export products FROM this website in xml, and it should show only one category tree per product. BUT in my website products should be visible in 2-3 category pages.

Comment: So add products as you normaly you would do and assign them to w/e categories you want. Then what i would do is to add additional meta in the parent category that i want to export. Then create a query and while you loop your products keep only the category with that additional meta field and build your xml. Or you can hardcode the categories you want in the xml if you need only for this specific case.

Comment: @MartinMirchev We managed to solve it by adding meta. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Glad to hear :) cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you can create shortcode and add it in archive page

```
    $theCount = $category->count;

    if ( ( is_product_category( 'your-current-category-slug' ) ) && ( $theCount > 0 ) ){

      ?>
add your current category product listing code here
<?php

    } else {

      

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product',
 'stock' => 1,
 'posts_per_page' => 2,
'product_cat' => 'add-your-category-slug-here-which-category-product-do-you-want-to-show',
 'orderby' =>'date',
'order' => 'ASC' );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
global $product; 
?>

Within loop we can fetch Product image, title, description, price etc. 


?>

<?php 
  endwhile;wp_reset_query();  

  echo 'There are no products in this category';

    }
```